# Megasync does not autostart

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, autostart, megasync

I installed the ubuntu(14.04 VirtualBox) version of megasync along with the nautilus extension. I typed "megasync" in my console, logged into my account, enabled autostart. But upon closing the console megasync just closes and when I restart the OS megasync does not start itself up.

Megasync is included in the startup options with command "megasync".

Note, I just installed Ubuntu and have no previous experience with Linux so this might be just a misunderstanding from my side, but I am helpless right now.

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems with autostart. In my case it was a prolem with permissions (megasync was not marked as executale), but I don't think yours is the same.

You can give it a try: sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/megasync

Or just run a script I've created to run multiple instances.

1) Log out from the session

2) Download and run my script [MEGA-Instances](https://github.com/bssec/MEGA-Instances) and follow the guide.